# crm 2013: Solutions for saving a child entity in parent form and navigate to the child entity in parent window

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement as followings:
1. Add an opportunity in the account form.
2. When clicking the save button, save the opportunity, and then open the opportunity in the parent window.

The environment crm 2013.

My solution is 
1. Add a custom event to the OnSave event of the opportunity form
2. use 'Xrm.Page.data.refresh(save).then()' API to save the opportunity entity first and then navigate to it in the original window.

After some investigation and testing:
The solution does not work.Because the method is registered with OnSave() event of the Opportunity form, it leads to an infinite loop.

To do something after saving an opportunity successfully, it seems the following two options would work:
1. Add a custom button overlapping with the system 'Save' button on the opportunity form, let the button do it (utilizing 'Xrm.Page.data.refresh(save).then()').
2. Listen to OnChange event on the parent Account form, check whether child opportunities have changed or not, it changed, retrieve the latest one, and navigate to it.

Any ideas about these 2 solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you "Adding the opportunity"? Are you using the native subgrid? Other component? A webResource?

Comment: I am using the 'Updated default Account Form' of the Account Entity. In this form there is 'SubGrid' named 'Recent Opportunities' in the 'Summary' area. on its right-upper cornner, there is a '+' button which opens a opportunity Iframe for you to create an opportunity and associate the created one to current account. In the 2nd solution, I need to somehow detect newly added opportunity.